# jodatime fetch date and update datepicker dialog on datechanged

Tags: android, datepicker, jodatime

I have the following method where I am fetching the date from the jodatime library and i have used a datepicker and timpicker to let the user select the date and time. I have made a button, onclick of that button the datepicker fetches the selected date and displays on the button, but the problem is , for the second time if i reopen the datepicker it shows the currentdate and time rather than the previously selected.

Here is my code,

```
    @OnClick(R.id.Button_due_date)
    public void show_DateTimePicker() {
    final View dialogView = View.inflate(AddFollowUp.this,       R.layout.datetime_picker, null);
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddFollowUp.this).create();

    dialogView.findViewById(R.id.date_time_set).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            final DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.date_picker);
            TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.time_picker);

            DateTime dateTime_jodatime = new DateTime(
                    datePicker.getYear(),
                    datePicker.getMonth() + 1,
                    datePicker.getDayOfMonth(),
                    timePicker.getCurrentHour(),
                    timePicker.getCurrentMinute(),
                    0
            );

            mFollowUpTime =datePicker.getYear()+ "-";
            if ((datePicker.getMonth() + 1) < 10) {
                mFollowUpTime =mFollowUpTime+ "0" + (datePicker.getMonth() + 1) + "-";
            } else
                mFollowUpTime =mFollowUpTime+ (datePicker.getMonth() + 1) + "-";
            if (datePicker.getDayOfMonth() < 10)
                mFollowUpTime = mFollowUpTime + "0" + datePicker.getDayOfMonth()+ " ";
            else
                mFollowUpTime = mFollowUpTime + datePicker.getDayOfMonth()  + " ";

            if (timePicker.getCurrentHour() < 10)
                mFollowUpTime = mFollowUpTime + "0" + timePicker.getCurrentHour() + ":";
            else
                mFollowUpTime = mFollowUpTime + timePicker.getCurrentHour() + ":";
            if (timePicker.getCurrentMinute() < 10)
                mFollowUpTime = mFollowUpTime + "0" + timePicker.getCurrentMinute();
            else
                mFollowUpTime = mFollowUpTime + timePicker.getCurrentMinute();



            String month_text = dateTime_jodatime.monthOfYear().getAsText();

            StringBuffer date = new StringBuffer();
            date.append(dateTime_jodatime.getDayOfMonth() + " ");
            date.append(month_text.substring(0, 3) + " ");
            date.append(dateTime_jodatime.getYear() + " ");
            date.append(dateTime_jodatime.getHourOfDay() + ":");
            date.append(dateTime_jodatime.getMinuteOfHour() + "");



           datePicker.updateDate(dateTime_jodatime.getYear(),dateTime_jodatime.getMonthOfYear(),dateTime_jodatime.getDayOfMonth());


            String day = CommonUtils.AddZero(dateTime_jodatime.monthOfYear().get());
            final String month = CommonUtils.AddZero(dateTime_jodatime.getDayOfMonth());
            String year = CommonUtils.AddZero(dateTime_jodatime.getYear());
            String hour = CommonUtils.AddZero(dateTime_jodatime.getHourOfDay());
            String minute = CommonUtils.AddZero(dateTime_jodatime.getMinuteOfHour());




            DonorDetails.Actual_Due_Date = day + "-" + month + "-" + year + " " + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + "00";



            mButton_due_date.setText(date);
            alertDialog.dismiss();

        }
    });
    alertDialog.setView(dialogView);
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

I have tried the datepicker.ondatechanged listener but it doesnt seem to work, i have also tried to use the datepicker.updatedate function which does not seem to work. Can anyone tell me how to make the datepicker show the selected date even for the second time?

here is my xml for the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="8dp">

<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/date_picker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:calendarViewShown="false"
    android:spinnersShown="true" />

<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/time_picker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/date_time_set"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"

    android:text="Set" />
```

Can anyone please suggest a solution?

Comment: you can pass selected date & time as a argument in which method  you want to call for display date & time picker and just using that value you can set the selected date

Comment: can u tell me how?

Comment: please refer this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_datepicker_control.htm

Comment: store all the selected date in variables and then pass it to the constructor second time

Comment: Im storing all the selected date in variables but how to pass it to the constructor ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set time to datepicker the next time you call it you will have to initialize it as follows

```
DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.date_picker);
datepicker.init(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth, DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener onDateChangedListener)
```

Note that Month will be set in ints from 0 to 11 where 0 is jan.
If you dont want onDateChangeListener then you can set it as null.

Initialize your datepicker below findViewByID and dont make it final.